# ANSI search in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to search some utf8 data which is stored as ANSI in mysql database (version 5.7)
with full text search, but no luck.

My query:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
str_test
WHERE
MATCH (txt) AGAINST ('à¤¬à¥‡à¤µà¤œà¤¹' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

**Table Structure**:

```
    CREATE TABLE `str_test` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `txt` text,
   `txt_hin` text,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   FULLTEXT KEY `txt_fulltxt` (`txt`),
   FULLTEXT KEY `txt_hin_fulltxt` (`txt_hin`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Data format:**

```
 id                         txt                                                       txt_hin                                                                                                                                                txt_hin
2   à¤¬à¥‡à¤µà¤œà¤¹ à¤¯à¤¾ à¤…à¤¤à¥à¤¯à¤§à¤¿à¤• à¤•à¥à¤°à¥‹à¤§  बेवजह या अत्यधिक क्रोध करने वाले का व्यवहार दानव 
3   à¤œà¥‹ à¤®à¤¨à¥à¤·à¥à¤¯ à¤¦à¥‚à¤¸à¤°à¥‹à¤‚                  जो मनुष्य दूसरों के प्रति अपने मन में जलन या द्वेष की
4   à¤¨à¥à¤¯à¥‚à¤œ à¤à¤œà¥‡à¤‚à¤¸à¥€ à¤•à¥‡                                                      न्यूज एजेंसी के मुताबिक,
```

My query should return row with id 2

Everytime my query is returning blank result set. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarity, what is meant by ANSI?

Answer (score 0):

Full text indexes store words. Your text doesn't look much like words, so even if the raw bytes match MySQL may not see them as word matches. Full text search is not exact. You probably need to ensure that you are using the same encoding everywhere and that MySQL is able to make sense of it.